# ServiceNow: Get list of cases with recent activity via REST API

Tags: rest, servicenow

I'm trying to get the most recently updated cases from ServiceNow, using the REST API.

I know I can run this call: `/api/sn_customerservice/{api_version}/case?sys_updated_on>={given date}`

The problem is that some background process updates the `sys_updated_on` field for many cases that don't actually have any activity on them. So a case that has a last activity from 2019 may have its `sys_updated_on` updated today.

I have no access to change the behavior of whatever is updating the `sys_updated_on` field.

I know I can pull a list of records and then make a second API call to  `/api/sn_customerservice/{api_version}/case/{id}/activities` to check the date of the most recent activity for a given case. But that's two API calls for every case (of which there are thousands).

Is there any way to get a list of just the cases that have had recent activity?

Limitations: this is a personal project and I only have access to the API with my user credentials. I don't have a development account.

Comment: Report the error to support instead of writing your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The design of Case API is to get case records
The design of activity endpoint within Case API is mainly to get activity stream details of given input case.

The usecase you have is - To get list of cases that have had recent activity. It definitely makes sense to first get the recent activities for all cases in a limited timeline like a day or a week and then only query details of those related cases to the activity stream records.

However to do this you will need to implement a scripted REST API to query `sys_journal_field` table and get case sys_ids which have recent activity in activity stream.